# Unable to access Circle class

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I have successfully added a map in my app but now I want to draw a Circle on it using the `Circle` class of the API.

When I try to import that class it is not showing up. Meanwhile, when I use the same code as another application it does show up.

Comment: check whether u have google play services library for your project

Comment: yes i have added it in my project but still not able to access only the Circle class

Answer (score 0):

GooglePlayServices library should be added to your project.So that u can get the Circle class.

Comment: yes i have added it in my project but still not able to access only the Circle class

Comment: how did u add it? can u be more precise?

Comment: Dear krisDrOid, i am getting the other classes of com.google.android.gms.maps.model package and i know that Circle class is available in the same package but it is not showing me, can you solve this please

Comment: it can be solved only by...if it was code i could have helped u out. Since it is related to addition of libraries to your project just make sure that, the google play services is updated to latest version. Also, whether you are using support library.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your sdk extra for Google Play Services? The [Circle](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) object was introduced in release 5, so if you have release 4 you won't see it.

Comment: hey @Mati thanks for the post but i have done this, still getting the same result,

Comment: Sorry, I saw this quite late. Which is exactly the problem you're having? Could you solve it?